# How to create a search model in django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create a search panel. There will be many fields to fill out and if user doesn't fill out something I want to select all records from database for this parameter.

And I am wondering how to do this in django model ? In raw MySQL that'd be ease, but I don't now how to set up conditions, for example ,

> if user filled out field **Name** select only this choice, if not,
>   select all

Are there best practices for this kind of problem ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Look at [http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html).

Comment: can you post your `views` file so that i can show how can you implement `Search` in django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets take the example of `Blogpost` project where i have a `index.html` page to render my data by using. So to search in that data i will use **[Field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups)**.

In this `BlogView` you can see i specify `query`, where if we get `q` in request it means `query` is not empty so it will run the `Filter` method where using `icontains` i can ask specify what to lookup e.g title in my case.

Don't forget to use **Double-Underscore** **`__`**, also referred as **dunder**

```
def BlogView(request):
query = request.GET.get("q", None)
blog = PostModel.objects.all()
if query is not None:
    blog = blog.filter(

            Q(title__icontains=query) |
            Q(content__icontains=query) 
            )
context = {
    "queryset": blog,
}
template = 'blog/index.html'
return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: this answer returns **unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'Q'** any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please post your code. Q objects are operations on field value and in your error it says *str*. Which means either your Q objects is missing a syntax or you've used some *str* variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at [django-filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter) package, use this module to provide your search fields

Comment: latest stable version in pypi says it's py2 compatible [link](https://pypi.org/project/django-filter/1.1.0/), also if it didn't work you might need to install an older version

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by creating dynamic field lookups with `Q` shown as below:

```
from django.db.models import Q

# queryets are lazy. So does not hit do db
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()    

query = Q()

for field_name, value in request.POST.items():
    if value:
        try:
            MyModel.get_field(field_name)
        except:
            # Field does not exist on model
            continue
        lookup = "{}__icontains".format(field_name)
        query |= Q(**{lookup: value})
        # query &= Q(**{lookup: value})

queryset = queryset.filter(query)
```