# django2 search form UnboundLocalError at /

Tags: python, django

I try to add a search box with this code's i got the error:

> Blank result

```
def home(request):
    if 'search' in request.GET:
        term = request.GET['search']
        name = Products.objects.filter(titulo__icontains=term)
    return render(request,'base.html', {'name':name})
```

in the model:

```
from django.db import models
    class Products(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
      def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

on the views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Products
def home(request):
    if 'search' in request.GET:
        term = request.GET['search']
        item = Products.objects.filter(name__icontains=term)
    return render(request,'base.html', {'item':item})
```

if i use this i got the error
local variable 'name' referenced before assignment
And if i add the variable name

```
from django.shortcuts import render
    from .models import Products
    def home(request):
        item=none
        if 'search' in request.GET:
            term = request.GET['search']
            item = Products.objects.filter(name__icontains=term)
        return render(request,'base.html', {'item':item})
```

edited the second view, with this i don't have results using

```
{{Products.name}}
```

on the html file
i also try with:

```
def home(request):
    query = request.GET.get('search',None)
    items = Products.objects.all()
    if query is not None:
        items = items.filter(
            Q(items__contains=query)
            )
    context = {'items':items}
    return render(request, 'base.html', context)
```

Comment: "I don't see nothing*" is probably an (incorrect) double negation?

Comment: refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320242/how-to-create-a-search-model-in-django/51401740#51401740

Comment: `{{ Products.name }}` wouldn't work in any case, since you never send anything called `Products` to the template.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a name be "unbound" in Python? What code can cause an \`UnboundLocalError\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101836/how-can-a-name-be-unbound-in-python-what-code-can-cause-an-unboundlocalerror)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all  your views, you make more or less the same mistake:

```
def home(request):
    if 'search' in request.GET:
        term = request.GET['search']
        name = Products.objects.filter(titulo__icontains=term)
    return render(request,'base.html', {'name': name})
```

You here define a variable, for example `name` *in* the `if` body. But now imagine that the condition in the `if` statement is *not* true, then it will skip the body. After the `if` body however you *use* the `name` variable. Now in case the statement is not true, you use a variable that was never defined.

You can fix this, for example by defining a default value first:

```
def home(request):
    name = Products.objects.all()
    if 'search' in request.GET:
        term = request.GET['search']
        name = Products.objects.filter(titulo__icontains=term)
    return render(request,'base.html', {'name': name})
```

So now in case the condition is not true, then the variable is still set, since we defined it *before* the `if` statement, here for example we return than all products.

In your second view, the same happens, but now the culprit is the `item` variable.